# Rooting Sony M4: fastboot flash recovery fails

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia

I used flashtools to unlock my bootloader and all seemed to go well. However when I try and do `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` (from the dir that contains "recovery.img" on my laptop) I get

```
writing recovery
FAILED <remote: Command not allowed>
```

I've tried relocking and unlocking the bootloader with flashtools to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: That makes it sound like the bootloader is still locked.  What do `fastboot oem device-info` and `fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability` say?

Comment: The first gives the same failed messaged as in my OP, and the second gives a "usage" dialog suggesting an invalid command. hm.

Comment: Few devices support the second command yet, but the rest is quite odd.

Comment: I did notice in many of the tutorials they say check "Enable OEM unlock" in Developer settings, but my device's settings does not have this option. Not sure if that's relevant or not. I did enable USB debugging there however.

Comment: It could be.  What version of Android do you have?

Comment: Android version 5.0. Build number (this is firmware version I assume?): 26.1.A.2.167. Model number E2303. I followed this tutorial for unlocking the boot loader :http://freeandroidroot.com/how-to-unlock-bootloader-in-sony-xperia-m4-aqua/  and used Flashtool v0.9.19.8 along with the minimal adb fastboot install. Flashtool reported success regards to unlocking, and allows me relock and lock again etc.

Comment: Maybe I need to downgrade the firmware to 26.1.A.1.128 before I can root? (see http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64308234&postcount=6)